# Explode a string into bidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, explode

Excuse me if this question was already solved. I've searched trough the site and couldn't find an answer.

I'm trying to build a bi-dimensional array from a string. The string has this structure:

```php
$workers="name1:age1/name2:age2/name3:age3"
```

The idea is to explode the array into "persons" using "/" as separator, and then using ":" to explode each "person" into an array that would contain "name" and "age".

I know the basics about the explode function:

```c
$array=explode("separator","$string");
```

But I have no idea how to face this to make it bidimensional. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work. The goal is to first split the data into smaller chunks, and then step through each chunk and further subdivide it as needed.

```
$row = 0;
foreach (explode("/", $workers) as $substring) {
    $col = 0;
    foreach (explode(":", $substring) as $value) {
        $array[$row][$col] = $value;
        $col++;
    }
    $row++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I supposed it had to be some kind of for inside for... I'm starting with programming and this kind of structures still make me dizzy xD

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array();
$workers = explode('/', "name1:age1/name2:age2/name3:age3");

foreach ($workers as $worker) {
    $worker = explode(':', $worker);
    $array[$worker[0]] = $worker[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$new_arr=array();
$workers="name1:age1/name2:age2/name3:age3";
$arr=explode('/',$workers);
foreach($arr as $value){
   $new_arr[]=explode(':',$value);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The quick solution is

```
$results = [];
$data    = explode("/", $workers);
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $line = explode(":", $row);
    $results[] = [$line[0], $line[1]];
}
```

You could also use [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) with a custom function which does the second level split for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach, not multidimensional:

```
parse_str(str_replace(array(':','/'), array('=','&'), $workers), $array);
print_r($array);
```

Shorter in PHP >= 5.4.0:

```
parse_str(str_replace([':','/'], ['=','&'], $workers), $array);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: every time i see your name I think of burt wonderstone and anton marvelton dancing and then burt pulls a woody out of a hat

Answer (score 1):

yet another approach, since you didn't really give an example of what you mean by "bidimensional" ...

```
$workers="name1:age1/name2:age2/name3:age3";
parse_str(rtrim(preg_replace('~name(\d+):([^/]+)/?~','name[$1]=$2&',$workers),'&'),$names);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [1] => age1
            [2] => age2
            [3] => age3
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks. By bidimensional I meant an array containing arrays as its elements... sorry if that's not exactly what "bidimensional" means. As I said, I'm newbie to programming. :)

Comment: @darent well, "multidimensional" is the correct term but I think we all understood what you meant. What **I** meant though is that there's different formats for it, as you can see in my and others' examples. Example my single top level "name" element vs. what a lot of others showed with multiple top level with a name=>value 2nd level. Which way is best ultimately depends on what you want to do with the data